# How to support parameter based search in MS Teams messaging extension?

Tags: python, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am using MS teams search based messaging extension to search notes and docs of my org.
[image]

Here i want to integrate search using some parameters to support filtering on the search results. Say, when the user choose Notes, i want to add another input box in parallel to this search box to take parameters e.g. Author,Tags etc.
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently adding another input box in parallel to message extension search box to take parameters is not supported. Please Raise a [user Voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform).